# THREE.JS Mesh position smooth animation

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

I have a pretty easy question for you with three.js about x position translation of an imported .obj mesh.

I'm fairly new to three.js and was wandering if someone could give me some lead on what to do or solve this problem.

So... I have this mesh on `(0,-200,0)` and i just wanted to move it to `(50,-200,0)` with a smooth translation through a button back and forth to the two positions.

```js
objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
 objLoader.load('models/map_real.obj', function (obj) {

      var blackMat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color:0xfaf9c9});
      obj.traverse(function (child) {

         if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
             child.material = blackMat;
         }

     });
     obj.castShadow = true;
     obj.receiveShadow = true;
     obj.position.set(0,-200,0)
     obj.rotation.y = getDeg(-20);
     scene.add(obj);
     objWrap = obj;

 });
```

I have in my main.js an `init()` which contains all the functions such as `camera(), animate(), render()` etc... and from the variable `objWrap.position.x` it logs the correct position.

I've tried to capture the click (as the snippet below shows) on my `#test button` and only increment the position by `0.5` - - i get this, is not in the animate loop so it cant keep add `0.5`.

```js
$('#test').click(function(){
    if (objWrap.position.x <= 50) {
    objWrap.position += 0.5}
});
```

**So the final result that i want is a button that toggle back and forth a smooth animation that goes from `objWrap.position.x = 0` to `objWrap.position.x = 50`**

I hope to have been clear, feel free to ask if you need to know more, i'll respond in seconds... All the help is truly appreciate!

Comment: Using of `Tween.js` library will help.

Comment: Thank you @prisoner849, could you make a fast sketch of the usage of the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an example of how you can do it with [`Tween.js`](https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/blob/master/docs/user_guide.md):

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.setScalar(50);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(200, 100));

var box = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "aqua"
}));
scene.add(box);

btnMove.addEventListener("click", onClick, false);

var forth = true;

function onClick() {

  new TWEEN.Tween(box.position)
    .to(box.position.clone().setX(forth ? 50 : 0), 1000)
    .onStart(function() {
      btnMove.disabled = true;
    })
    .onComplete(function() {
      btnMove.disabled = false;
      forth = !forth;
    })
    .start();

}

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  TWEEN.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/94/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tween.js/17.2.0/Tween.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnMove" style="position:absolute;">Move</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This works with `ReactJS`,

import TWEEN.

```
import {TWEEN} from "three/examples/jsm/libs/tween.module.min";
```

Enable drag controller and tween animation.

```
const { gl, camera } = useThree();
const objects = [];   // objects.push(ref.current)

useEffect(() => {
    const controls = new DragControls( objects, camera, gl.domElement );

    controls.addEventListener( 'dragend', (e) => {
         new TWEEN.Tween(e.object.position)
             .to(new Vector3(x, y, z), 1000)
             .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Back.InOut)
             .start();
    });
})
```

UseFrame to show the animation.

```
useFrame(() => {
    TWEEN.update();
});
```

Hope to help someone.